# Multiple instances of ArangoDB on same server

Tags: arangodb

Having looked through the docs and come up empty, I was hoping someone could help me.

I would like to run two copies (same version) of Arango on the same machine - one for live, one for test, on different ports.

I would prefer not to setup docker environments or similar just yet.

Any help much appreciated - OS is Ubuntu but would take advice for any OS.

Comment: Did the answer fullfill your needs? If yes, can you please mark it as accepted? if not, whats missing?

Comment: To be totally honest, i couldn't get it to work immediately, and then other things have become more important. I will test it out properly before the week it out and set to selected as appropriate. Thx for the reminder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the documentation here: [ArangoDB Docs](https://docs.arangodb.com/FirstSteps/Arangod.html) it looks like it should be as simple as specifying the database directory and the port for the second service:  So you would create a configuration file and make sure it has:

```
server.endpoint: What IP address and port to bind to
log parameters: If and where to log
database.directory: Path the database files are stored in
```

Then start it like this: arangod --configuration myconfigfile